# Raspberry Pi installing Tensor-flow and Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install Tensorflow 1.14 and Keras 2.0 but it keeps giving me an issue when I try to import it. It seems to install correctly but then just fails.

I am running Pi 3b+ Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

The error it is giving me is:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/cvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/pi/cvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/pi/cvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
from . import random
  File "/home/pi/cvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "/home/pi/cvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
from .mtrand import RandomState
ImportError: /home/pi/cvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

Comment: How did you install numpy and tensorflow/keras? Seems your numpy is broken, use a system provided numpy, not a third party one

Comment: I created a virtual environment and installed it using pip

Comment: Well try not using a virtual environment, and a system provided numpy

Comment: I give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `libatlas` to make [numpy](https://www.piwheels.org/project/numpy/) work

```
sudo apt install libatlas3-base
```